# How to restrict LINQ query to marketing lists of a given campaign?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using LINQ to query the CRM, and below you can see what I already have. The goal is to restrict the query to marketing lists, that are attached to a given campaign. How can I do this in LINQ (with late binding)?

```
List<Guid> GetLists(OrganizationServiceContext context, Guid campaign)
{
    var lists =
        from list in context.CreateQuery("list")
        where /* list is attached to campaign */
        select (Guid)list["listid"];
    return lists.ToList<Guid>();
}
```

Comment: does list hold a foreign key to campaign ..?

Comment: @otzap No its an n:m relation between campaign and list. Otherwise I'd use `where (list["campaignid"] as EntityReference).Id.Equals(campaign)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Premise: I upvoted the question because it's very interesting (I like LINQ against late bound) and the entities involved are not so easy to be queried.

First the code:

```
var lists = from list in context.CreateQuery("list")
    join campaignlist in context.CreateQuery("campaignitem") on list["listid"] equals campaignlist["entityid"]
    join campaign in context.CreateQuery("campaign") on campaignlist["campaignid"] equals campaign["campaignid"]
    where (Guid)campaign["campaignid"] == campaignId
    select (Guid)list["listid"];
```

And now the explanation:

As you already know `list` and `campaign` are connected with an N:N relationship, first thing to do is to find the relationship name, inside CRM it's under the relationship properties, in this case is `campaignitem`.

The second thing to do is to find the foreign key names of the relationship, normally they are `entitynameid` (so we can expect `listid` and `campaignid`) but in this case not. Instead of `listid` we have `entityid` (this because this relationship holds not only the relationship between marketing list and campaign but also between campaign and products and others as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, can I always just use `(Guid)entity["fieldname"]` for entity reference fields, or do I need `(entity["fieldname"] as EntityReference).Id`? Also, I think the second join is not necessary since we already got the campaign ID in the campaignitems. What do you think?

Comment: depends, normally I use `Guid` for the primary keys, and `EntityReference` when it's a lookup

Comment: So `(Guid)campaignlist["campaignid"]` in your answer should use `EntityReference` as well?

Comment: that field is considered as foreign key so it's a Guid, I also removed the unnecessary cast

Comment: I see. Can I directly cast any reference fields to Guids when I'm only interested in the Guid? I think foreign key is the same as entity reference in CRM.

Comment: they are not the same, you will get a cast exception (but I don't want to test it right now :))